# When I call glFinish() does that mean OpenGL ES ignores further calls until I call -setCurrentContext:?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, concurrency

In the [OpenGL ES Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH5-SW5) they say:

> To summarize, your app needs to call the glFinish function to ensure
>   that all previously submitted commands are drained from the command
>   buffer and are executed by OpenGL ES. After it moves into the
>   background, you must avoid all use of OpenGL ES until it moves back
>   into the foreground.

Does glFinish make OpenGL ES ignore all further function calls?

Or how else would you prevent your app from calling OpenGL ES functions after it begins transition to the background?

Problem is if you invalidate a timer that triggers async drawing with GCD serial queue a block still finishes its work in the middle of entering background.

Comment: No, you unfortunately misunderstood this document. `glFinish (...)` flushes the pipeline and blocks until all OpenGL commands finish, its purpose is to synchronize the CPU and GPU. The easiest way to prevent your application from making an OpenGL call after some point would be to set the thread's active context to NULL. It will not prevent you from making the calls *per-se*, but it will prevent them from doing anything.

Comment: But doing the calls per-se, as you say, does cause an app to crash if it is in the background already? The documentation is clear about that calling a open gl function after app is in background results in termination.

Answer (score 2):

glFinish() will block until all previous calls to OpenGL ES has completed their functions and thus the clears the pending tasks. This function is usually helpful to be called before you do any Screenshots.

To avoid GL calls while the app goes to background, is rather simple and it depends more on the way you have implemented your game loop. In our games, we use a BOOLEAN variable 'isAppActive' which will be triggered when the app goes to background state. If this variable is TRUE the Draw() function in the gameloop is not called. Thus avoiding all GL calls.

Comment: Yes of course. Now what do you do if your drawing code is happening asynchronously. Any nanosecond after you check the boolean your could be in the background already. How do you deal with that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html
I guess, it does not happen as both work in the main thread.

Comment: So your app does all openGL calls on the main thread to stay away from the background crash problem?

Comment: Both on iOS or Android OpenGL ES calls cannot be called on other than main thread.

Comment: @codetiger - "OpenGL ES calls cannot be called on other than main thread": That's not true, at least for iOS. You certainly can perform OpenGL ES rendering on a background thread. What you have to watch out for is that you can't access an OpenGL ES context simultaneously from more than one thread. A lockless method like a serial GCD queue is ideal for this, and I use it all the time to do OpenGL ES rendering from a background thread. You get some nice performance benefits for doing so.

Comment: @BradLarson Oh, sorry then. So you mean rendering to Texture is possible on background thread. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @codetiger - No, you can also render OpenGL ES content safely to the screen from a background thread. Again, you have to watch out for simultaneous accesses to the same OpenGL ES context, but it can be done just as easily as rendering offscreen.